# No Element in Xpath with lxml : Javascript Generated Page

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, lxml

I have had Xpath work with other things before, in the Chrome browser I can find my xpath in the console with $x('//*[@id="profile"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]) at https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/Fuzzyllama/duo?region=na.

When I try to get this element in code it returns an empty array, anybody know why?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def checkChrisPubg(ctx):
    page = requests.get('https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/Fuzzyllama/duo?region=na')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    duoRank = tree.xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]')
    print(duoRank)
```

print(duoRank) gives me []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I tried to do this with PyQt4 and had no real success in practice, a simpler but slightly more invasive resolution is to use Selenium, a webdriver for loading web pages.

I am sure there are multiple solutions to this but I was having a *hell of a time* even knowing what was wrong until I found my solution.

When using **lxml** you should ensure the data you are trying to grab **is not generated by javascript**. To do this you can **open Chrome Developer tools**, **click the menu**(3 vertical dots), **go to settings**, **go to the bottom**, **disable Javascript**, and **reload the page**.

If **nothing is there**, the **page is generated content with Javascript**.

A **simple solution** is below, this will wait for the page to render and then let you parse the tree with lxml.

This solution will require that you use these imports(You must install selenium):

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Now, you can load the page and start scraping:

```
#Load in your browser(I use chrome)
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
#Choose url you want to scrape
url = 'https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/Fuzzyllama/duo?region=na'
#get the url with Selenium
browser.get(url)
#get the innerhtml from the rendered page
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

#Now use lxml to parse the page
tree = html.fromstring(innerHTML)
#Get your element with xpath
duoRank = tree.xpath('//*[@id="profile"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/text()')
#close the browser
browser.quit()
```

My original solution would have been nice, but just didn't work because much of it is deprecated.

Comment: This is for sure a working solution to this problem, I can't mark it for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

What library are you using as a parser?

If `xml.etree.ElementTree`,

> ElementTree provides limited support for XPath expressions. The goal is to support a small subset of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of the core library.

http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm

Comment: I was using the full etree library, I am able to grab xpaths for data from static pages, dynamically generated pages were an exclusive problem.
Edit: lxml just didn't wait for JS to load first, PyQt4 solved this. It can also be done with Selenium, it just seems a bit bloated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Open page source `view-source:https://pubgtracker.com/profile/pc/Fuzzyllama/duo?region=na` here is the **script** with json `playerData` at line **491**. Just parse it.

Comment: You could do that but have you seen that data? Definitely not something I want to try and parse. Those keys don't help as they are re-used between elements through the hundred/thousands of lines of code. I would have to somehow count to the index of the value I want.
Edit: That also doesn't get the element in the xpath.

Comment: For anyone who would like to see how this indexing would work out, I won't post the source because it is crazy long. The index would be:
playerData.Stats[0].Stats[9].ValueDec; I had to manually pretty print the data to figure out the indexes, could get very lengthy.